# In an ISAPI Filter, what server variable gives me the physical path of a virtual directory?

Tags: windows, iis, isapi

If I have an "application" defined in IIS Manager, I can get the value of the server variable `APPL_MD_PATH` to retrieve the physical path associated to the application.

If I have a "virtual directory" configured,  `APPL_MD_PATH` still gives me the physical path associated to the application, not the physical path associated to the virtual directory.

- How can I retrieve the physical path to the virtual directory to which the current request is associated?
- How can I determine whether the request is being served from an application versus a virtual directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`HSE_REQ_MAP_URL_TO_PATH_EX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524961.aspx) to find the physical path of any URL.

If you want to tell whether you are in a vdir or not, simply start walking up the URL by stripping off one rightmost segment at a time. Call [`HSE_REQ_MAP_URL_TO_PATH_EX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524961.aspx) until you either a) hit the application root or b) hit a physical directory which has a different prefix than the previous one. If (b) then you are in a virtual directory.

You can also use the approach above to find the physical path of the current vdir.